# Accessing ansible variable properties with property names as other variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have the following code:

```
- name: "Get output from ec2.py"
  shell: python convinventory/ec2.py
  register: ec2_py_output
- set_fact:
    EC2_MY_AP_HOST: "{{(ec2_py_output.stdout | from_json ).myIPs[0]}}"
- set_fact:
    EC2_MY_AP_DATA: "{{ (ec2_py_output.stdout | from_json)._meta.hostvars. }}-{{EC2_IFX_AP_HOST}} "    //Need to know the syntax on this line
```

I confirmed that `EC2_MY_AP_HOST` returns a string ip like `10.0.1.2`

The json structure I received from `python convinventory/ec2.py` is like below:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "10.0.1.2": {

    < need to access this data in EC2_MY_AP_DATA > 
}
} } }
```

What is the correct way to access this data?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of this question and I can't. What's the relation between `10.0.1.2` and `10.0.36.13`? Where is the `myIPs` list stored (why isn't it in the example you posted, certainly not for clarity, because there's no clarity at all)? What data do you need to access and in what way? Are you asking what to put after the dot (how can anyone know)? Are you asking how to refer to the dictionary `10.0.36.13` (it's in all docs and FAQs describing accessing the facts coincidentally named `hostvars`)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

```
- set_fact:
    EC2_MY_AP_DATA: "{{ (ec2_py_output.stdout | from_json)._meta.hostvars[EC2_MY_AP_HOST] }}"
```

But my guess is that your are on the wrong path, and there's different solution to the task you try to solve with this code.